# “This project requires a Visual Studio update to load” error when creating a Xamarin.Forms Cross-Platform Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

When I create a `Xamarin.Forms` application using `Visual Studio Community 2015 Community` on Windows 8.1 it shows me this error on load:

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App1.WinPhone'. This project requires a Visual Studio update to load. Right-click on the project and choose 'Download Update'
```

I've installed all updates available and trying on a newly installed Windows.

Note: I had this error in Forms.

How can I fix this error?

Note: There isn't a Download Update option in Solution Explorer.

Comment: What is your VS2015 version? Update 2 is the latest.

Comment: Install Update 2 for VS2015

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uninstall Xamarin completely, and reinstall it. That happened to me as well. I would uninstall Visual studio too. Install that first, then install Xamarin.

Edit: I know this sucks to do, but it was what the Xamarin team had me do to resolve it. As far as I know this is the official fix as of last week.

Comment: I didn't have been installed Xamarin seperatly, I have installed Visual Studio with Xamarin for Android tools enabled. Then modified Visual Studio with all the cross browser plugins... Okey, now I will try this. So okey firstly I will uninstall Xamarin, then will uninstall Visual Studio, and then install Visual Studio without selecting Xamarin, afterwards install Xamarin from Xamarin.com setup file. Is this right?

Comment: @mrbengi that is correct. Uninstall order is not as important. Just make sure the install order is correct. You may still have to run updates on visual studio and Xamarin.components after installing Xamarin (Visual studio seems to require this). There might be some files in AppData that you might want to remove as well. I believe they are only Android files, but I could be wrong. I had to clean them either for this issue or for another that was causing my Android builds to fail.

Comment: @Sanjisan Can you point me to the thread where Xamarin people suggested this?

Comment: @akshay2000 It was via email. Is there something you would like to know from it in particular?

Comment: @Sanjisan I was hoping to hop on the same thread and ask them about UWP support in that app. Also, I REALLY hate reinstalling. I simply do not have the bandwidth. It would take weeks to finish.

Comment: @Sanjisan Looks *user3458211* solution is proper one.

Answer (score 7):

Navigate to where you saved the project files that you created in Visual Studio. Default location is `C:\Users\PSDan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects`.

Open the project folder that you are experiencing problems with and navigate to `C:\Users\PSDan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\test\test.Windows` folder. Inside this folder is a file called `test.Windows.csproj`.

Right click on that file and open with... using Visual Studio, by doing this it should detect the missing package and in my case automatically prompted to install the missing package.

Comment: Yep, this does it. :D

Answer (score 3):

I've been seeing similar errors for .Window or .WindowPhone and what I've observed is that it is due to missing SDK. Same might be the case with you.

Do you see App1.Droid appearing in the solution? (I guess NO)

Go to file explorer and locate App1.Droid.csproj (..\App1\App1.Droid\App1.Droid.csproj) and open this in a new instance. There it will pop up "Install Missing Feature" dialog and you can follow the steps to install missing components.

Comment: Hmm okey, I will try this and will inform here, too

Comment: Yes I saw for .Windows and .WinPhone. I corrected the question.

Comment: Did you try "Installing Missing Features"? i.e. followed steps mentioned?

Comment: Mine was Forms as well

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is the same as here:

[Project required a Visual Studio update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443568/this-project-requires-a-visual-studio-update-to-load-error-when-creating-a-xam/36528889#36528889)

then you may try and see if this solution works:

[Cause is] a mismatch of the target framework version and profile in the .csproj file. Despite the target framework being correct in the project Properties, they were not being correctly saved for whatever reason. Thus, when trying to install a utility library from nuGet, it left my project in the state you described.

The solution was to go by this site:

[Framework Profiles in .NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html)

and find the correct combination, then manually edit the .csproj file to adjust `<TargetFrameworkProfile>` and `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Visual Studio Update 3 with selected features "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1" and "Cross Platform Mobile Development" solved the problem for me.